# SQL admin not sys admin

Tags: sql, sql-server, admin

I have an sql server with multiple databases. 
I have an admin role on a user. 
Is possible to give that user special permissions to create other users? users that will have access to other db but not the primary db?
Basically i want to know if an user that is not sysadmin could create other users.

Comment: Create [*users*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql) or create [*logins*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql)? (Either way, those pages show what permissions are required to be able to execute them)